# Shortcuts for specifying multiple variables in SPSS

Tags: spss

Are there any shortcuts codes in SPSS for listing multiple variables? Say something similar to `v1-v3` instead of `v1 v2 v3` in SAS data step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some commands allow you to use the `TO` modifier (but not all). This is dependent on variables being in correct order in the data matrix. There are also multiple response sets, and defining macro calls to a specific set of variables.

Below I give examples of using `TO` and defining a set of variables via a macro. I admittedly never use multiple response sets, so I can only state it is an option (more useful for a set of dichotomous items than continuous variables I believe).

```
set seed = 10.
input program.
loop #i = 1 to 100.
compute id = #i.
compute V1 = RV.NORM(0,1).
compute V2 = RV.UNIFORM(0,1).
compute V3 = RV.POISSON(3).
compute V4 = RV.BERNOULLI(.5).
compute V5 = RV.BINOM(5,.8).
end case.
end loop.
end file.
end input program.
dataset name sim.
execute.

freq var V1 to V5 /format = notable /statistics = mean.

DEFINE !myvars () V1 V2 V3 V4 V5.
!ENDDEFINE.

set mprint on.
freq var !myvars /format = notable /statistics = mean.
```

Comment: The `to` options works with `reliability /variables .`. Thanks also for the warning about data set variable order. I would have assumed the command `v1 to v3` to sort the variables out automatically.

Answer (score 2):

TO is always based on file order.  It would be rare IMO to want a list selected by an interval in alphabetical order. Commands that accept a list of variables pretty much all honor TO.

You can change the variable order by using the KEEP subcommand of MATCH FILES.

You can also define a macro for a list of variables and reference it where you need the list.

Finally, if you install the Python Essentials from the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral) and the SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES extension command, the dialog box makes it easy to define a macro based on file order, alpha order or measurement level, among other criteria.

HTH